# Why does the position of jcenter(), maven(), google() matter in the build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've come across many cases of resolving dependency issues by just replacing positions of gradle repository `jcenter`, `maven()` ,`google()`.i.e moving one on top of the other. i am confused as why is it so or is it a bug in Android Studio...?

Comment: probably dependencies are looked up in repositories according to the order of repositories in the list...